# jeasyui: How to prepend a Row instead of appendRow in datagrid?

Tags: jquery, datagrid, jquery-easyui

I want to prepend Row in datagrid. There is method available to `appendRow` but no method for `prependRow` in datagrid of EasyUI (http://www.jeasyui.com/).

I want to insert new row in the TOP ONLY.

At the moment I am using this code:

```
$('.selected_items').datagrid('appendRow',{
  description: 'description',
  qty: 1,
  price: '33',
  upc: '11',
  price_with_tax: '33'
});
```

This code is working fine for appending a row. But I want to insert in the top.

Please someone guide/suggest me how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

you can try to put the code like this

```
$('#dg').datagrid('insertRow',{index:0,row{id:'',field1:'',field2:''}});
```

this will insert the row on the top because it set `index:0` and you can set wherever you want the row will be insert to.
I am using this. hope it will work out for you